# call property change call back when it's properties has updated

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, dependency-properties

I have a class A that has some properties,
in class B, I create an object of A and made it `DependencyProperty` and register `propertyChangedCallBack` for it. but it just fires when object of A recreated not when it is updated.
How can I solve it to be called even when a sub property of A is changed not the whole object?

Comment: property of property is not beeing handled by propertyChangedCallBack. Your property is a pointer to the class-A-object, whichs property change without changing Bs reference to its A-object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built in way of 'deep linked' property change notification. You will have to do it on your own.

Your `class A` could contain another event `Changed` (just an example; name it as you like), which is raised everytime one of its members is changed

```c#
public class A
{
  private string name;      
  public string Name
  {
    get { return this.name; }
    set 
    {
      if (value != this.name)
      {
        this.name = value;        
        this.RaiseChanged();
      }
    }
  }

  // ... more properties here ...

  public event EventHandler Changed;

  private void RaiseChanged()
  {
    this.Changed?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
  }
}

public class B
{
  public A PropertyA { get; set; }
}
```

Your `class B` then has to subscribe to `PropertyA`s `Changed` event and in turn inform the outer world about the change to `PropertyA`. Remember to handle changes to `PropertyA` correctly.

Just for notification purposes there is no need for (and no extra use in) making `PropertyA` a DependencyProperty, so you can just stick to `INotyfyPropertyChanged`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want OnPropertyAChange event fires . public static readonly DependencyProperty PropertyAProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("PropertyA", typeof(A), typeof(B), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnPropertyAChange));